# Date() function not recognized by Access 2013 web application

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am attempting to create a query using the design mode of Access 2013 (because I cannot find the SQL view). This is a web app btw.

I have a column, LastUpdated, of the Date type.

I want to find all where LastUpdated is more than 6months old.

Anytime is use Date() I get "The expression you entered has a function name that MS Access can't find."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access 2013 uses a different date function for Access 2013 Web Apps. In the web apps, use [Today()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249622.aspx)

[DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj248961.aspx) is also slightly different for web apps.